# Graphics Tablet with "click + drag" capabilities without driver installed

Tags: mouse, ergonomics

I'm looking to use a graphics tablet at work as a mouse alternative, but their lame IT department won't let me install any drivers. Although my monoprice and huion graphics tablets can be used without installing a driver, there is only left-click functionality. Sadly, my work requires the ability to click and drag, as well as right-click, which only works if you install the drivers for these particular brands. Is anyone aware of a graphics tablet out there that can do right-clicking as well as clicking and dragging without having to install the driver? My tendons are getting worn out over here, I'm desperately looking for a solution for overusing the traditional mouse. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are required for any input and output device to function as intended. You can find a driver for your huion tablet here http://www.huion.com/download/ locate the  drive by putting in your **PRODUCT MODEL** and the **OPERATING SYSTEM** you are currently using it on. I am unfamiliar with the monoprice so i can not assist you with that brand.

Comment: “IT department won't let me install any drivers.” - The author isn’t allowed to install a driver.  The author is likely aware where to locate their graphic tablet’s driver.

Comment: what is your model?